# Reduced row echelon form of a matrix using trig

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have this problem and my trig is weak:

A =

```
  cos a   sin a

 -sin a   cos a
```

where A is a 2 x 2 matrix.

I need to put A into reduced row echelon form (RREF)

Appreciate the help--I know it's a very easy question.

Comment: The determinant is $1$ so the RREF will have to come out the identity matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

- $\tan a \times R_1 + R_2 \rightarrow R_2$
- Divide $R_2$ by what is left over from the last operation.

Can you finish it off?

**Spoiler**

> After a few row operations, you will end up with the $2 \times 2$ identity matrix, which we already knew from the fact that our determinant is one.

Comment: what do you mean by 'what is left over from the last operation?

Comment: What is your second row after you do the first bulleted item, what is left as row 2?

Comment: After that operation $R_2$ is 0    tan(a)sin(a)+cos(a). Don't know how to make the 2nd row, 2nd col, entry into a 1 from here.

Comment: How about simplifying $\tan(a) \sin(a)+ \cos(a)$?

Comment: This is where my trig weakness is rearing its head: When I simplify I get: cos(a)+(1-cos^2(a))/cos(a). Don't know how to simplify this.

Comment: $\tan x \sin x + \cos x = \dfrac{\sin x \sin x}{\cos x} + \cos x = \dfrac{\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x}{\cos x} = \dfrac{1}{\cos x} = \sec x$. Got it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10820/discussion-between-n8sty-and-amzoti)

Comment: Needs a thumbs up! +1

Comment: Thanks, Amzoti! Visiting MSE this morning before I launch off to Round II ;-). Thanks for remembering! Not doing so hot at MSE this a.m.

Comment: @amWhy: Me too! :-) Monday's seem like off days for me! :-)